# Select a preferred value from an aggregated column when using GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with id and langcode (and some more) columns.
If the row is the default language (in this case german), default_langcode is 1.

```
|id | langcode | default_langcode |
###################################
|1  | de       | 1                |
|2  | de       | 1                |
|3  | de       | 1                |
|3  | en       | 0                |
```

Now I want to select each id only once, and preferably non default_langcode row.

```
|id | langcode |
################
|1  | de       |
|2  | de       |
|3  | en       |
```

When I use this query I get each id once, but I don't know how to specify to prefer to select the 'en' langcode.

```
SELECT id, langcode
FROM table
GROUP BY id;
```

Does anybody know how I would achieve this?

I could do `MAX(langcode)`, but this wouldn't work if the langcode is something smaller than 'de'.

I guess an alternative would be to UNION all rows with en langcode and the rest which is not in the first set of rows, but this is rather convoluted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation with conditional logic:

```
select id, 
       coalesce(max(case when default_langcode = 0 then langcode end),
                max(langcode)
               ) as langcode
from t
group by id;
```

Alternatively, you can use `union all` and `exists`:

```
(select t.id, max(t.langcode)
 from t
 where default_langcode = 0
 group by id
) union all
select t.id, t.langcode
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.default_langcode = 0
                 );
```

That is, select non defaults.  Then select an arbitrary language code when there is no default.

Comment: Thanks! I like the first one. I changed `default_langcode = 0 `  to  `langcode = 'en'` to specify a langcode

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need a union and a having to be added

```
   SELECT id, 'en'  
    FROM table
    GROUP BY id having count(distinct 
       langcode) >1

      union

      SELECT id, langcode
    FROM table
    GROUP BY id having count(distinct 
       langcode) =1
```